# cakephp two paginations on one controller and one view

Tags: cakephp, pagination

I have a controller that has two paginations which is reflected in my view but anytime I want to click on page 2, the controller doesnt know which page it is clicking on and I get an error.

```
class AsController extends AppController 
{
  public function view ($id = null)
  {
    $data1 = $this->paginate('Post','Post.foriegn_id' => $id);
    $data1 = $this->paginate('Author','Author,foreign_id' => $id);
    // rest of the code goes here
  }
}
```

I have two sections in my view page

```
<div class="post view"> and div class="author view"
```

And in each of tehse sections I have the following code:

```
<div class="paging">
<?php
    echo $this->Paginator->prev('< ' . __('previous'), array(), null, array('class' => 'prev disabled'));
    echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('separator' => ''));
    echo $this->Paginator->next(__('next') . ' >', array(), null, array('class' => 'next disabled'));
?>
</div>
```

Please assist me in any way to rectify this issue

Cheers

Comment: There's a section in the book for multiple paginations - have you read that yet?  http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html#query-setup

Answer (score 0):

It looks like its more of a structure/design issue. You are using the same id to get posts and authors. Do you have a relationship between posts and authors you can just paginate through one of the models? From what I know the pagination built into cake is meant to work with one model per request. Especially due to how the pagination helper uses the url params. Do you have a case where you want to show page 1 of posts and page 2 of authors? Also in your view action you have your second paginate() saving to the same $data1 var which is overwriting the previous. Not sure if this is a typo.

I would suggest only using one main section of pagination per page. If the data of the authors relates to the posts I would suggest containing and displaying it in the same paginated section.

Comment: check out something like what we have here on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394524/how-to-paginate-multiple-results-in-cakephp  But my database as is a database with a primary key and authors and posts databases both have foreign keys linking to the primarky key of as databae.

Comment: If this is still an issue for you can you post what errors you are getting? It sounds like you might have to configure the pagination settings separately.